# How to set the value a second time in a text box using selenium if it doesnt get set properly the first time?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

On the application I work , after tabbing out of every field, there is an AJAX call , some blue spinner at the bottom . If we enter text in a field while the spinner is present , field doesnt retain its value , is it possible to to write some while loop or something ...

which checks whether value has been set properly or not otherwise re enter it

Thanks

I have tried 
**Send Keys**
**Javascript Executor**
**But they dont work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(element.getAttribute("value").isEmpty() == true) {
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='someInputText';", element);
}
```